# Reimplementing dos2unix and unix2dos in C++; '\r' and '\n' not appearing in hexdump?

Tags: c++, char, hex

I'm trying to reimplement `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` in C++. Here's my `dos2unix`:

## dos2unix

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// save as d2u.cpp, compile '$ g++ d2u.cpp -o d2u'
// execute '$ ./d2u sample.txt'
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string fn ="";
    char c;
    if (argc == 2) { fn = argv[1]; }
    ifstream is(fn.c_str());
    ofstream os("temp.txt");
    while (is >> c) {
        switch(c) {
            // 0x0D = '\r', 0x0A = '\n'
            case 0x0D: break;
            case 0x0A: os << (char)0x0A; break;
            default: os << c; break;
        }
    }
    is.close(); os.close();
    string command = "mv temp.txt " + fn;
    system(command.c_str());
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Since DOS text files will have newlines ending in `\r\n`, I want to ignore the `\r` and only output `\n` to the new file. Testing it with a text file and comparing the hexdumps, however, shows nothing is done except all `\r` and `\n` are removed:

## Hexdump of input

```
74 65 73 74 0d 0a 74 65 73 74 32 0d 0a 74 65 73 74 33
t  e  s  t  \r \n t  e  s  t  2  \r \n t  e  s  t  3
```

## Hexdump of output

```
74 65 73 74 74 65 73 74 32 74 65 73 74 33
t  e  s  t  t  e  s  t  2  t  e  s  t  3
```

## Hexdump of expected output

```
74 65 73 74 0a 74 65 73 74 32 0a 74 65 73 74 33
t  e  s  t  \n t  e  s  t  2  \n t  e  s  t  3
```

Why does this happen? I get similar behavior with my implementation of `unix2dos`.

Comment: You should open the files in binary mode to avoid automatic line ending conversion.

Comment: use `is.get(c)` and `os.put(c)` instead of `<<` and `>>`.

Comment: Also recommend `'\r'` and `'\n'` instead of `0XD` and `0XA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid having `>>` eliminate whitespace from your input, the easiest change is simply to use `is.get(c)` instead of `is >> c`. [std::basic_istream::get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) behaves as an *Unformatted* input function and will provide a character-by-character read of everything in the file. The [std::basic_iostream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_iostream) operator `>>` provides for *Formatted* input which eliminates whitespace.

Changing to istream.`get()` provides the behavior you describe,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::string fn {};
    char c;

    if (argc < 2) { /* validate filename provided */
        std::cerr << "error: filename required.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    fn = argv[1];

    std::ifstream is (fn.c_str());
    std::ofstream os ("temp.txt");

    while (is.get(c))
        if (c != '\r')
            os.put(c); 

    string command = "mv temp.txt " + fn;
    system(command.c_str());

}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/fleas2line.txt
my dog has fleas
my cat has none
```

**Example Use/Output File**

You can see the `'\n'` is preserved in your input.

```
$ hexdump -Cv temp.txt
00000000  6d 79 20 64 6f 67 20 68  61 73 20 66 6c 65 61 73  |my dog has fleas|
00000010  0a 6d 79 20 63 61 74 20  68 61 73 20 6e 6f 6e 65  |.my cat has none|
00000020  0a                                                |.|
```

temp.txt

```
$ cat temp.txt
my dog has fleas
my cat has none
```

Lastly, avoid using `0XD` and `0XA` in your code and instead use the characters themselves, e.g. `'\r'` and `'\n'`. It makes the code much more readable. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a reason you advise to move away from hex and use strictly `\r` and `\n` besides readability? I figured it would be easier to examine a hexdump with them congruent.

Comment: Readability is it. `'\r' == 0xd` and `'\n' == 0xa`, so you are free to use whichever you like. The general consensus is to use the literal character when you mean the character.